# YouTube Player API never fully loads?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a web page that uses the YouTube Player API.  I am **not** having the problem of **onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()** never being called.  It definitely is called.  Instead, when that function is called, the YouTube API is not fully loaded.  This leads to the constructor exception "*yt.player is not a constructor*" when I try to create the player instance in that method, because **YT.Player** has not been defined yet.  If I check the status of the YT object, I see that it does exist but it's top level properties show these values:

```
{loading: 1, loaded: 0, ready: ƒ, setConfig: ƒ}
```

As you can see the **loading** field is still TRUE (equal to 1) and the **loaded** field is still FALSE (equal to 0).

Out of desperation I changed my code from below:

```
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
    {
        console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() called.");

        player = new YT.Player('player', 
        {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: "i8MOJho5TDs"
            events: 
            {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    } // function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
```

To a version that uses an Interval to poll the **loaded** field for a TRUE (equal to 1) value.  If it is not TRUE then a new interval is set to try again 100 milliseconds later, using this code:

```
   function createYouTubePlayer()
    {
        if (!YT.loaded)
        {
            console.log('YouTube Player API is still loading.  Retrying...');
            setInterval(createYouTubePlayer, 100);
            return;
        } // if (!YT.loaded)
        console.log('YouTube Player API is loaded.  Creating player instance now.');

        player = new YT.Player('player', 
        {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: "i8MOJho5TDs", // 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: 
            {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
    {
        console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() called.");

        setInterval(createYouTubePlayer, 100);
    } // function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
```

Here is the function that loads the YouTube API.  It is called from a **script** tag in the **HEAD** section of the HTML document:

```
   // This function initialize the YouTube IFrame Player API.
    function initializeYouTubePlayerAPI()
    {
        // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        console.log("YouTube Player API load initiated.");
    }
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't help because the **loaded** property of the YouTube API YT object never changes to TRUE (equal to 1).  Therefore I see a stream of console messages showing the endless retries while the code waits for the YouTube Player API to fully load.

**Does anyone now why this is happening or how I can fix it?**

Note, I *did* try this operation from incognito mode in Chrome in case the problem was due to interference from a Chrome extension.  That didn't help so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I turned out I made a simple mistake.  I forgot to include this Javascript file at the top of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```